# What kind of data structure is used for immutable maps?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

I know how normal mutable maps work (using hashtables), and I know how immutable lists work (recursive linked lists) and their advantage over mutable lists (constant time appending without messing up the original) but how do immutable maps (e.g. Scala's) work?

I know the advantage of not messing with the original map when generating new maps, but how does the underlying data structure work, and what kind of performance characteristics do they have, for example compared to mutable hash tables? Is there any standard data structure which people use to implement these, that I could go look up in CLRS/wikipedia?

Comment: CLRS, and pretty much every other data structure / algorithm textbook are *heavily* biased towards mutability and impurity. Chris Okasaki *literally* wrote the book on Functional Datastructures, which is based on and an extension of his earlier thesis work. Other works you should look at are by Phil Bagwell and Rich Hickey.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Persistent *Hash* maps are implemented using a structure called a **[Hash trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie)**. It was [originally proposed by Phil Bagwell](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/papers/idealhashtrees.pdf) (who is a member of the Scala group at EPFL) but actually implemented by Clojure first. It hit scala when **2.8** came out in 2010.

There is a [great talk on functional data structures](http://vimeo.com/28760673) by Dan Spiewak where the mechanics of the hash trie are explained extremely lucidly (along with other things such as banker's queues)! He also explains asymptotic big-O performance very well in the talk.

Last October saw Phil give another talk at the [London scala Lift Off](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/parallel-algorithms-data-structures), this time on parallel persistent data structures.

Persistent sorted maps are implemented via a [*Red-Black* tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

Comment: In general, persistent data structures rely on *structural sharing* (e.g. persistent cons lists share their tails). Typically, you use trees for that. If you understand how persistent cons lists work, you're halfway there: after all, a list is just a degenerate tree with only one branch everywhere. (Or, a tree is a generalization of a list, where each cell can have more than one successor.)

Comment: I think the interesting information is how to connect that understanding with how it pertains to hash-based access

Answer (score 1):

It could be a tree (red-black) or a hash map.  Their access characteristics depend on the underlying implementation.  A tree is O(log n) for read access; a hash map is O(1).